# How to Open Desktop Properties from CMD?

Tags: cmd, location, desktop

First post here..

I'm writing a program and I need to change the location of the Desktop from Java, (or CMD).

Is there a CMD command that will open the Desktop properties? (where you can modify the location of the desktop)

Thanks,

Comment: Wait, there's an option for that? (Windows doesn't usually let you change the locations of things that can break it all to hell if they're wrong.)

Comment: I have never seen an option to do this. This is probably downvoted because it would be better asked on Super User. What problem would such a change solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the location in the registry.

The following batch file example should set the location to `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`, *(which is the default)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Desktop" /V "Path" /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D "%%USERPROFILE%%\Desktop" /F >Nul
```

I'll leave it to you to change it to a single cmd.exe command if you'd prefer to do it at the Command prompt or if you think changing the registry another way would be easier for you.

You can enter any valid UNC name or mapped drive in the value of this entry. *Just remember that as this is an EXPAND string, you should double up the percent characters if using variables you want to expand when accessed.*